# calender control in asp.net opening in another form

Tags: asp.net

I am using calender control in asp.net 2.0, and after clicking on button its opening in another form.  I am using the following JS code to open the window:

```
 function openwindow(txtvalueID) {

        leftVal = (3500 - screen.width) / 2;
        topVal = (800 - screen.height) / 2;

        if (txtvalueID == 'ctl00$CPH1$txtHireDate') {
            var txtid = '<%=txtHireDate.ClientID %>';
        }
        else {
            var txtid = '<%=txtTermDate.ClientID %>';
        }
        var frmid = '<%=Page.Form.ClientID %>';
        var qs = "formname=" + frmid + "." + txtid;

        window.open('/Calender.aspx?' + qs, 'calendar_window', 'fullscreen=no,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,directories=no,location=no,width=230,height=240,left=' + leftVal + ',top=' + topVal + ',screenX=400,screenY=400')
    }

    function isNumeric(keyCode) {
        return ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 8)
    }
```

In this line `txtvalueID == 'ctl00$CPH1$txtHireDate'` is wrong.  I am referring to the control id, but the control id keeps changing.. Why?

Comment: my application is working fine but still want to be sure is it fine to address with control id.. does it change... soemtimes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't explicitly refer to the ID directly, but instead do:

```
if (txtvalueID == '<%=txtHireDate.ClientID %>') {
```

In the first if line, that will help with the ID changing issue.

HTH.